# Formal/informal/slang terms for front passenger/co-driver

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Could any native English speakers help me with some formal, informal, slang, or even some local (Scottish, Welsh, Irish, etc.) terms for "front passenger". I mean the term for a person that travels with somebody in a car (boat, aeroplane, train) next to the driver or even in the back-seat, etc.

Comment: What is wrong with passenger?

Comment: It has no affiliation with the driver. The best word for me is co-driver, however I would like to avoid the word driver if possible. Is there e.g. any other word similar to co-driver?

Comment: But you ask for the "front passenger" then ask for a back-seat passenger. Which do you want? Your question is ambiguous.

Comment: Please, note the word "even". That means, it is the last thing I am interested in. Mostly I am interested in "front seat passenger next to the driver/pilot" term alternative.

Comment: It does not mean what you think it means. Using *even* in that way means that it is an added requirement. E.g. I want a coat that keeps me warm, even in the middle of winter.

Comment: OK, so what would be a better word to use in this scenario instead of even?

Comment: If you're not interested in back-seat passengers, don't mention them. I don't understand why you've mentioned them. you either want a word that includes them or you don't. If it doesn't matter, you could say "It's OK if the term includes back-seat passengers, but I'd prefer it didn't" or "It would be good if the term worked for back-seat passengers too, but this isn't important." depending on if you do or don't want to include back-seat passengers.

Comment: @MattЭллен: Derfder's use of even here is legitimate and mean ssomething different from your (legitimate) usage. In context it means 'possibly also but is not the main thing'. 'even' does that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common slang term for riding next to the driver is "to ride shotgun". Apparently there is also the term "cobain" for the seat behind the shotgun seat but I've never encountered that one. Here's a source for both usages: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shotgun&defid=709676

Comment: You're welcome. When you scroll down in the link, you're offered an explanation on how the term allegedly came to be.

Answer (score 3):

"Shotgun" is by far the most common slang term for the passenger (or more precisely, the passenger *spot*) that's next to the driver/pilot.  "Copilot" is another term I've heard a lot, and can refer to either a literal co-pilot in an airplane as well as the metaphorical "co-pilot" of a car or other vehicle.

Comment: In addition to "co-pilot," I've jokingly used "navigator" on occasion, particularly when the passenger would be helping me with directions, or even just holding the GPS device.